# Connecting to a Web Service running on Visual Studio Development Server from another machine

Tags: visual-studio, web-services

I have a web service running on machine A on Visual Studio's build-in Development Server.
For testing purposes, I'd like to test the service by connecting to it from machine B, which is in the same subnet.

Is this possible? Or is VSDS restricted to localhost calls only?

-pom-

Comment: Commenting to myself: There is a nice blog post explaining the usage of port forwarding here http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2009/09/03/accessing-the-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server-from-iphone.aspx

It seemed at first to solve my problem, but for some reason it doesn't work on my vista machine. Trace Utility won't show any incoming calls. Any calls to web service with IP address fail from both machine A or B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio's Web Development server doesn't support remote connections. You might need to install IIS for this purpose or some proxy server like [Squid](http://ashleyangell.com/2009/03/configuring-a-basic-reverse-proxy-in-squid-on-windows-website-accelerator/).

Comment: You can also use Fiddler as the proxy.